# Renci ssh.net No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it

Tags: c#, asp.net, sftp, ssh.net

We recently deployed a project into production and are now receiving this error message when we attempt to connect to the external sftp machine, "No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it".  When I was developing the application and testing it, we had no issues connecting to this server.

What would be different? I have administrative privileges and the app pool on the production server does not. I'm not sure if this could be what's causing the issue or if it may be something on the external client's server or their firewall blocking us.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a standard TCP error

`WSAECONNREFUSED  - 10061`

From the Client's point of view it means 'there is no socket at that address listening to that port'  (the "actively refused" is a red herring).

i)   check the address
ii)  check the port
iii) check firewall(s)

Comment: Thank you this pointed us on the right track.  Our firewall was a little to strict and our DMZ couldn't receive the ack from the sftp server.

Answer (score 12):

If you are using `localhost`, specify `127.0.0.1` instead.

When I was using SSH.Net and the host was specified as `localhost` it threw the exception that the host actively refused the connection `WSAECONNREFUSED  - 10061`. When I specified `127.0.0.1` instead, the connection could be made.
I think this is due to the implementation in SSH.Net:

```
    internal static IPAddress GetIPAddress(this string host)
    {
        IPAddress ipAddress;
        if (!IPAddress.TryParse(host, out ipAddress))
            ipAddress = Dns.GetHostAddresses(host).First();

        return ipAddress;
    }
```

Which does not resolve a valid hostname for `localhost`, apparently. C# Interactive yields the following:

```
> Console.WriteLine(Dns.GetHostAddresses("localhost").First());
::1
```

The value `::1` does not seem to be a valid IP address for sockets to use.

Answer (score 1):

From our extensive experience (we offer own networking components) -- it's a firewall problem. The firewall doesn't let your requests pass. It's a common situation when you run say Putty, and it works, but your code doesn't. This is because many firewalls detect well-known applications and let them pass, while preventing other applications.

Comment: Exactly, the firewall was too strict for our DMZ and it was blocking the ack from the sftp server.  Thank you!